# related objects queries django rest framework

Tags: django, subquery, django-related-manager

I have the following models

```
class STUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    companyname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class VenuePermissions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(STUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    signupvaildatestring = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I want to grab all the `STUser` objects and grab all their permissions.

So what I would like is to grab all the `VenuePermissions` objects. And grab the `user` and `venue` object of each venuePermission

Two ways I can do this. use the `VenuePermissions_set` attribute on `STUser` but then how do I grab the venue when its just going to be a `pk` value?

Or focus on the `VenuePermissions` objects and grab the user and venue from the pk values but how?

I remember nested queries, and I kinda did one in my browse code.

here is an example:

```
 rooms = Room.objects.filter(venue=OuterRef('pk'), sixtyroundseatingoption= True)
            venuelist = venuelist.annotate(sixtyrounds=Exists(rooms))
            venuelist = venuelist.filter(Q(sixtyrounds = True) | Q(fullbuyoutsixtyroundseatingoption = True))
```

I've done the set objects in a serializer before

Example serializer:

```
class RoomAndImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    roomimage_set = RoomImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('pk','name')
```

any help with this query would be appreciated!

So this is what I am currently trying, I will post an answer if this works:

```
class VenueUserList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VenueUserListSerializer
    queryset = VenuePermissions.objects.select_related('user').select_related('venue').filter(signupvaildatestring=None)

class VenueUserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    venue = VenueSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = VenuePermissions
        fields = ('user', 'venue', 'isvenueviewer', 'isvenueeventplanner', 'isvenueadministrator')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer. However I still need to group venues by user. Working on that.

```
class VenueUserList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VenueUserListSerializer
    queryset = VenuePermissions.objects.select_related('user').select_related('venue').filter(signupvaildatestring=None)

class VenueUserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    venue = VenueSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = VenuePermissions
        fields = ('user', 'venue', 'isvenueviewer', 'isvenueeventplanner', 'isvenueadministrator')
```